# Can't create UE5 C++ Project

Tags: visual-studio, project, unreal-engine4, unreal-engine5

I tried creating c++ project on ue5 but it gave me this error:

[Unreal Engine 5 Project Error Img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g0sFE.png)

Creating a c++ project in ue4 works fine, I can also create ue5 project but in blueprints only.

How do I fix this error so I can create an ue5 c++ project?

Comment: Have you tried installing the .net core as in the error message?

Comment: Yes, I did download the SDK 6.0.101 Windows x86 installer and installed. Then I tried creating a new project and got the same error. I'm not sure but I think I'm supposed to move the installation into this (D:\UEVersions\UE_5.0EA\Engine\Binaries\DotNET\UnrealBuildTool\) folder, right? I tried to do that, however, I couldn't manage to find where the installation was located, so I couldn't move It into the expected folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:** I installed the .NET Core 3.1 SDK x64 and was able to create a UE5 C++ game project.

---> *Found the solution in the UE Forums.*

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried installing C++ editor?
as example, you can install visual studio.To add C++ tools to your VS installation, make sure you select Game development with C++ under Workloads. that worked for me

Comment: Yes I've done that. I've added the required tools.